# Should my custom control rely on Controller classes or Interfaces?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, custom-controls, javafx-8

Suppose I make a custom control in my application. This custom control can be housed in another layout's FXML file, or added dynamically through code. The parent container housing this custom widget has to be able to respond to its changes.

Should my custom widget utilize INTERFACES (polymorphism) or CONTROLLER passing?

The former requires that any parent class dynamically adding it to their layout implement the WidgetInterface so that it may handle changes.

The latter lets controller classes pass themselves in during construction so that the widget can tell the parent controller to act upon changes. This best works with FXML injection. The problem with this method, however, is that it only lets one parent controller class control the widget.

How can my widget be utilized by any class, anywhere, and be easily injected from FXML without problems? Via the injection method, it will try to call initialize() and rely on a controller class when there might not be one.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the best alternative is to use Controllers since they, as you said, work well with FXML injection.

I don't see how letting one parent controller class control the widget is a bad thing since a class can implement interfaces of your choosing and even extend another class, inheriting its methods/attributes.

Plus, you can even use Scene Builder to easily manipulate the widget if you do import your fxml into scene builder.